# create a custom post type with taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to create a custom post type with taxonomy. When I activate my plugin I see all categories of post on dashboard. But I display only taxonomy categories not post categories.

```
function propertyinfo_setup_post_types() {

    $PROPERTY_labels =  apply_filters( 'propertyinfo_labels', array(
        'name'                => 'Property Info',
        'singular_name'       => 'Property Info',
        'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'propertyinfo'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Property', 'propertyinfo'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit Property Info', 'propertyinfo'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit Property Info', 'propertyinfo'),
        'new_item'            => __('New Property Info', 'propertyinfo'),
        'all_items'           => __('All Property', 'propertyinfo'),
        'view_item'           => __('View Property', 'propertyinfo'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search Propertys', 'propertyinfo'),
        'not_found'           => __('No Propertys found', 'propertyinfo'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No Propertys found in Trash', 'propertyinfo'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => '',
        'menu_name'           => __('Property Info', 'propertyinfo'),
        'exclude_from_search' => true
    ) );


    $PROPERTY_args = array(
        'labels'            => $PROPERTY_labels,
        'public'            => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category',),
        'publicly_queryable'=> true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_in_menu'      => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'capability_type'   => 'post',
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'supports'          => apply_filters('propertyinfo_supports', array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail','author') ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'propertyinfo', apply_filters( 'propertyinfo_post_type_args', $PROPERTY_args ) );

}

add_action('init', 'propertyinfo_setup_post_types');
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Do you mean that when you check out your custom Post Type in the admin area, `Categories` is not listed under it? If that is the case, try removing the comma directly after `category` in the `taxonomies` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register taxonomy is different.

add this code and remove `taxonomies' => array('category')` from property args.

```
register_taxonomy("main_title", array("Property Info"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "cat_lable", "singular_label" => "singular_label", "rewrite" => true));
```